# How to know that it is a developer account in Play billing library?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, play-billing-library

I use managed item for in-app billing using Play billing library 1.0.
The managed item is a premium feature, and it becomes possible to use the full feature.

I usually log in to the phone with the same account as the Developer Console.

In that case, I can not make in-app purchases from the Play store, within my own developed app.
That means that I can not use the full feature with my own app, developed by myself.

```
BillingClient.ResponseCode returns 6 (unknown error).
```

It alone can not know that it is a developer account.

How to know that it is a developer account in Play billing library 1.0?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options I can think of:

- Have a second version of your app which doesn't check for the managed in-app product, instead it always gives the full version. [Release this on an alpha track](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213), and only have your developer account on the alpha track. That way you (and only you) will get the version that doesn't need the purchase
- Use the [Play License Verification Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html) to check the user has installed from Play. In the [ResponseData](https://github.com/google/play-licensing/blob/master/lvl_library/src/main/java/com/google/android/vending/licensing/ResponseData.java) for that is a field `userId`. Check what that comes out for for you, and have a special case for your developer account.

Comment: Thanks.
I have a hard time managing two apps.
Therefore, I will try out the Play License Verification Library.